# R confusion matrix change order of columns

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

```
confusion_table = table(actuals, predicted_values)
print(confusion_table)

       predicted_values
actuals   0   1
      0 102 110
      1  48 440
```

I want to flip the order of confusion matrix .i.e 1,0 in rows and columns

```
                            predicted
expected output actuals     1  0
                      1
                      0
```

How do I change this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse the order of the rows and columns

```
table(0:1, 0:1)
#   
#    0 1
#  0 1 0
#  1 0 1

table(0:1, 0:1)[2:1, 2:1]
#   
#    1 0
#  1 1 0
#  0 0 1
```

So on your data, try

```
table(actuals, predicted_values)[2:1, 2:1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert the original column/vector to `factor` and specify the levels in that order and then do the `table`.

```
table(factor(0:1, levels=1:0), factor(0:1, levels=1:0))

#   1 0
# 1 1 0
# 0 0 1
```